# How to play an .mp3 using QBuffer with Phonon in a PyQt Qt environment

Tags: pyqt, mp3, buffer, phonon

With the code I have right now I CAN play .mp3 data from files succesfully.
However I need to play the same data using a QtCore.QBuffer (NOT from a file).
When I use the example of the docs it errors an unexpected type of QBuffer!
However...... that is what it SHOULD see, according to the docs.

But............... it throws:

TypeError: Phonon.MediaObject.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QBuffer'

The code I use is (1):

```
    someBuffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
    someBuffer.writeData(TrackData)
    mediaObject.setCurrentSource(someBuffer)
```

I also tried (2):

```
    someBuffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
    mediaObject.setCurrentSource(someBuffer)
    someBuffer.writeData(TrackData)
```

and (3):

```
    someBuffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
    someBuffer.writeData(TrackData)
    mediaObject.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(someBuffer))
```

The last example (3) throws an different ERROR and wipes my Gui off screen ;-)

```
 
    ASSERT: "d->connected" in file /builddir/build/BUILD/phonon-4.5.1/phonon/streaminterface.cpp, line xxxx
```

**Notes:**
 TrackData contains the mp3 data and IS PLAYING OK when I write it to a File and use that as a resource to mediaObject.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource())I also experimented with a QByteArray but that leads to the same  "unexpected QBuffer" error. To be more precise everything I feed setCurrentSource is not accepted. Tried a string (errors an unexpected type of String), tried a QBuffer (errors an unexpected type of QBuffer), tried a QByteArray (errors an unexpected type of QByteArray).

BTW: I run Qt, PyQt on Linux.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

From the [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/phonon-mediasource.html) docs, it looks like `setCurrentSource` expects a `MediaSource` object. `MediaSource` objects can be initialized with `QIODevice` objects; `QBuffer` is a subclass of `QIODevice`. Perhaps you need to wrap your `QBuffer` in a `MediaSource`:

```
someBuffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
someBuffer.writeData(TrackData)
sourceWrapper = Phonon.MediaSource(someBuffer)
mediaObject.setCurrentSource(sourceWrapper)
```

The documentation seems to suggest that you shouldn't need to do this, that the `MediaSource` object should be implicitly constructed. I think they might be wrong though. I just did a quick test: calling `setCurrentSource` on the `QBuffer` raised an error like you got. However, wrapping it in a `MediaSource` and calling `setCurrentSource` on that worked fine.

Comment: I tried your sample code and even other methods but it still is not working. Did you really test that with .mp3 data? Did it play sound?

Comment: I did, and I've just tested it again. It plays fine.